# jquery ajax post and get in single page

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to post some data and get those data. On page load i am showing the data. it works. but once i post the data, it is posted in db but not showing in the page. after loading the page only it shows.

i need to show the data once it is posted in the same page without page reload.

here is my code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "employees.php",
              success: function(data) {   
                    $("#result").html(data);
              }
    }); 

    $("#create").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var age = $("#age").val();
        var gender = $("#gender").val();
        var salary = $("#salary").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "create_employees.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: 
                {
                    name:name,
                    age:age,
                    gender:gender,
                    salary:salary
                }
        }).success(function (response){
            console.log(response);

        });
    });
});
```

```
<form>  
    Name  : <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br />         
    Age   : <input type="age" name="age" id="age"><br />  
    Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="male" checked>Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" value="female">Female<br />``
    Salary: <input type="text" name="salary" id="salary"><br />   
    <button id="create">Create</button> 
</form>  
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're not showing the data anywhere on the page.  Take a look at your AJAX success handler:

```
.success(function (response){
    console.log(response);
})
```

It does exactly one thing... log the response to the console.  Nothing else.

What do you want it to do?  What is `response` and how will you update the page with it?  Well, that's up to you really.

Is `response` HTML data?  You can append it as the contents of an element:

```
$('#someElement').append(response);
```

Is `response` JSON data?  You can use values from it to set some HTML values:

```
$('#anElement').text(response.someValue);
```

And so on.  The point is, if you want to display the data on the page then you need to write the logic to do exactly that.  The system has no way of automatically doing it for you.

Comment: can you help me how to display the same data in a table?

Comment: @I.George: If you've made some attempt and something isn't working, that sounds like a good candidate for another Stack Overflow question.  If you're just asking how to make a table in HTML, there are a variety of tutorials and examples you can find online to help with that.